# TRIGGER that checks if that delete removes all the table values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Basicly I just don't wanna allow that `DELETE FROM X` delete ALL rows.

For example:

`DELETE FROM X WHERE ID = 3 OR ID = 4;`  --> Allowed because don't try to remove all table.

`DELETE FROM X;` --> Not allowed because it will be delete all table.

How I can do it with a trigger?

Comment: What if there are only two rows: 3 and 4?

Comment: Then no, needs 1 row minimum to work, but I think if controll if its DELETE FROM X will be enougth

Comment: You can't do this with a trigger, because the trigger executes within one transaction. You can't see whether there is potentially another transaction run by another client concurrently that is deleting the last row. That is, neither your transaction or the other transaction are deleting _all_ the rows, but once both of you commit, there will be none left.

Comment: Can maybe i get query trying to execute in trigger?

Comment: Aß described in above comments it is not easy to avoid this. Possibly it is easier to change the condition that you need on column. Why Is this neccessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not actually need a trigger to prevent `delete` without a `where` clause.

You may be able to do what you want just by setting:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

The documentation for this is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates).

Note:  This of course applies to all tables.  If you only want this restriction on one table, then a trigger might be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I just wanna in one table, can you help me?